# Google Smart Home Actions add device '[test] ACTION is linked' to immediate 'Something went wrong. Try again'

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am creating a new Google smart home Action, and step one is to create an OAuth 2.0 server for account linking.

https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2?oauth=code&hl=ko&refresh=1

I have follow all of the steps on the Google documentation under the Auth code UP UNTIL 'start the authentication flow'. I do not know if this is required or where this code would go, but that is a different topic.

However, there is an error with my Authentication page. Linking is done with my iPhone's Google Home app, currently which has the generated [test] prefix. When I click the [test] MYAPP, the service runs through till the redirection correctly. The webpage closes and informs me 'MYAPP is linked. As soon as this notification disapears, a new notification 'Something went wrong. Try again' appears.

Clicking the [test] MYAPP to link any time afterwards leads to a blank webpage that says 'Account now linked', but the MYAPP does not move to the 'linked' portion of the Google Home app.

https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/error-logging

After checking the logs, I was initially getting 'OPEN_AUTH_FAILURE' for days. Now, I am getting 'BACKEND_FAILURE'.

What is the next step? How can I debug this?

Comment: Any logs of the event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to verify that your account linking implementation is working properly. Here is how you can configure this tool to test your endpoint:

1. Open the **Settings** gear, change **OAuth endpoints** to **Custom**
2. Enter your authorization and token URLs from the Actions console
3. Enter your client ID and secret from the Actions console

You won't be authorizing any Google APIs, so for **Step 1** you can just enter something like "devices" and click **Authorize APIs**. You can follow through with the flow in Step 2 to verify that the authorization and token exchange work properly. The tool will report if any errors occur in the flow.

If you can successfully verify your account linking implementation, but you are still seeing errors returned in the Cloud console, please [file an issue](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/support).